# Retrieving value of b with getElementByTagName and making it integer

Tags: javascript, html, regex, google-tag-manager

First of all, I am new to JavaScript. I have been pulling my hair getting this to work. I have tried a lot of different approaches, but I just cannot get it working. What I want to do, is pull a value from a HTML document with JavaScript, and save the value from: `<div class="sum">Sum of order: <b>530 SEK</b></div>`. What I want to grab is the integer, **530**, and strip it of everything else.

HTML:

```
<div class="order">
        <div id="departDate">
        <div><b>Departing:</b></div>
        <div>2015-08-08</div>
    </div>

        <div id="returnDate">
            <div><b>Returning:</b></div>
            <div>2015-08-16</div>
        </div>

        <div><b>Tickets</b></div>

        <table>
            <tbody><tr>
            <td class="first">Adult(s)</td>
            <td>1 x</td>
            <td>530 SEK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="noborder">
        <td colspan="3">
        <table>
        <tbody><tr>
        <td id="people102" class="query first" style="font-size: 11px;">Test Testsson</td>
        <td id="info102" class="query text-red" style="font-size: 11px;"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="first">Children:</td>
            <td>3 x</td>
            <td>0 SEK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="noborder">
            <td colspan="3">
        <table>
        <tbody><tr>
            <td id="people9999" class="query first" style="font-size: 11px;"></td>
            <td id="info9999" class="query text-red" style="font-size: 11px;"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        <div class="sum">Sum of order: <b>530 SEK</b></div>
        <div class="vat">VAT 6%: 30 SEK</div>
</div>
```

What I have been figuring I'd try to do, is to grab the `<b>` value through `document.getElementsByTagName("b")[3];` but it just isn't working when I try to either parse it or replace it using regexp. A full example of what I am trying to do:

```
function my(){ 
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("b")[3]; 
var str = b.toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
var x = str.parseInt(); 
return x } 
my();
```

This says that str.parseInt is not a function. If I strip that part down with:

```
function my(){ 
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("b")[3]; 
var str = b.toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
//var x = str.parseInt(); 
return str } 
my();
```

it returns `[object HTMLElement]`. How should I proceed to retrieve the value, stripping it from everything except the digits and replacing it with nothing and then returning its value? Reading other posts of retrieving a string and extracting it as an Integer is what got me trying these things out. I know what I want to do, just not the technical expertise to getting it done.

If I do

```
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("b")[3];
console.log(b)
```

I get `<b>530 SEK</b>`. How come I can't work with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. Use the text content of the dom element
2. Use the global `parseInt` function

**1. You have to use the text content of the dom element:**

```
var str = b.textContent.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

**2. `parseInt` is a global function, not a member function.**

So instead of

```
var x = str.parseInt();
```

use

```
var x = parseInt(str, 10);
```

Comment: This worked great. Thanks! I felt like I was on the track of something, but I couldn't nail the exact part of where I was going wrong. Also, thank you for explaining my errors and how to solve them, and explaining parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

you can try one of `parseInt()` or `ParseFloat()`, depends on what do you expect to get as a text, on `textContent` property of the node:

```
var b = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("b")[3].textContent);
console.log(b)
```